# does $\frac 1{x^2} = \frac 1{x+1}$ ? and if so how?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to evaluate the limits of $$\frac {x-2}{x^2 - x-2}$$ as $x$ approaches $2$.

I can see that $$\frac {x-2}{x-2} \to 1 $$

therefore the equation becomes $$\frac 1{x^2}$$

however checking on symbolab.com this becomes $$\frac 1{x+1}$$

How is this so ? Surely $$(x^2) = (x * x)$$

This  link (https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto2%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bx-2%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D-%5Cleft(x%2B2%5Cright)%7D%5Cright/?origin=button) shows the workings out on symbolab, which I do not understand.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please use parentheses.

Comment: Just for reference, I think he's canceling the terms "$x-2$" in the fraction $\frac{x-2}{x^2-x-2}$.

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question pretty heavily.  Please check to see that I didn't introduce any errors.  I can't follow your calculation...I think you are incorrectly asserting that $\frac a{x+a}=\frac 1x$.  Just plug in some values to see that this is not generally an equality.

Comment: "therefore the equation becomes 1/x^2".  It does???? Why?  $x^2 - x - 2 = (x-2)(x+1)$ so I think the equation "becomes" $1/(x+1)$. How did you get it becomes $1/x^2$??  ... Oh, I think you are doing $\frac {b}{a + b} = \frac 1 a$.  I do hope you realize why that is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is this:

$$\frac{x-2}{x^2-x-2}$$

Factoring the denominator:

$$=\frac{x-2}{(x-2)(x+1)}$$

Cancelling like factors:

$$=\frac{1}{x+1}$$

The equation should not become $1/x^2$ when you cancel the factors for the removable discontinuity.

Comment: Thankyou, this has cleared things up for me :)